# COM vs WMI for Information providing

Tags: windows, com, hardware, wmi, hardware-interface

What is better method to use if I would like to provide the user with some information
about my **Hardware device.**

Should I develop a proprietary COM Library or should I develop a WMI provider?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that's a no-brainer: WMI is the Microsoft-blessed way of providing performance and hardware information.

That should be the way you provide the information you describe. There's plenty of precedent in the Win32_Computer and other hardware classes, which provide CPU details, memory size and so on (stuff that doesn't change with the software running).

I say that since you specifically marked out "hardware device". Don't think that WMI is for reporting just software type things like memory usage or process lists.

There's a large amount of software out there already specifically built to query WMI (including one of mine) so there's no shortage of people who will know how to do it.

Answer (score 5):

WMI is very good. Play a bit with using this tool [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en), good for learn WMI.